# how to get audit rule in acl object with getauditrules() on registry key in powershell?

Tags: powershell, acl, audit

I am trying to apply audit rules with this code

```
function add-acl($Right,$Access)
{
$audit = "mydomain\myaccount","$Right","containerinherit","none","$Access"
$r = new-object system.security.accesscontrol.registryauditrule $audit
$acl.addauditrule($r)
}

$acl = get-acl hklm:\software\_test
add-acl "CreateSubKey" "Success"
add-acl "Delete" "Success"  
add-acl "Delete" "Failure"  
$acl | set-acl
```

but this code writes audit rules without taking account of earlier rules.
So I wanted to retrieve audit rules before applying the code.
To do so, I used the method getauditrules() :

```
$acl.getauditrules($true,$true,??)
```

In ?? position, I tried NTaccount object and windowsSecurity. It doesn't return an error and in fact does not return something at all. This is really disapointing because while using windows interface, I can see that an audit rule is applied.
I don't understand what type of object is expecting the getauditrules() method.
Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding the `-audit` paramenter to `get-acl` cmdlet ( this retrieve  `SACL` , `System Access Control List`).

```
$acl = get-acl hklm:\software\_test -audit
```

the you can use:

```
$acl.getauditrules($true,$true, [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount] )
```

or

```
$acl.getauditrules($true,$true, [System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier] )
```

based on your goal.

Comment: Excuse me for the bump, but is there a way to produce results by calling .NET methods rather than a powershell cmdlet? I've done extensive testing on powershell cmdlets before and the I/O ones in particular (both file and registry) are much slower. I know 1ms vs 3ms doesn't seem much, but when you want to map the entire registry it's definitely going to be noticable.