# Windows command to display advanced audit settings of Registry Keys

Tags: powershell, registry, command-prompt, audit, regedit

Using commands on Windows, I am trying to display the advanced audit settings of Registry Keys. I have tried to do this on powershell and cmd with admin privileges but I have had no luck in doing so. After a load of research and testing I have managed to craft commands to display the registry key permissions using the commands below on powershell and on CMD, I feel like I am very close but I cant seem to find the right parameters.

**powershell:**

```
(Get-Acl -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion).AuditToString
```

**command prompt:**

```
 C FOR /F "tokens=3 delims= " %A IN ('reg.exe query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography" /v "MachineGuid"')`
 DO @icacls %ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\76944fb33636aeddb9590521c2e8815a_%A
```

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13509667/how-to-get-audit-rule-in-acl-object-with-getauditrules-on-registry-key-in-powe

Comment: Thank you for the assistance, looking at that post, I modified my command to the following: get-acl hklm:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run -audit  and it does not give me the correct results, have I formatted it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I tried this:

```
PS C:\> (get-acl hklm:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run -audit).GetAuditRules($true,$true,[System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])


RegistryRights    : FullControl
AuditFlags        : Success
IdentityReference : fffff\tom
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit
PropagationFlags  : None
```

Is this what you expect?

Comment: Thank you, this works on the admin prompt, but I need it to work on a regular powershell prompt. do you know how to do that?

Comment: I tried to find an easy answer for this. In short: Its not easy.
To read the Audit Rules you need to have the SeSecurityPrivilege in the System. This corresponds to the Permision "Manage audit and security log" which is by default granted to Administrators only. My recommendation is not to change this.